# In RStudio, how can I print out the result of integration in one single line with a string?

Tags: r, r-markdown, cat

```r
miu <- integrate(func, lower=0, upper=inf)
print(miu)
```

I compute a mean by integration in RStudio, and if I print the output directly, it is a sentence, **"10.60002 with absolute error < 0.00014"**. How can I print the sentence right after **"The true mean is"** in one single line? `cat()` cannot handle it because `miu` itself is in fact a list. And if I do the below, the two parts would be seperated in two blocks in the pdf output.

```
print("The true mean is:")
print(miu)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this:

```
print(paste("The true mean is:", miu$value, "with absolute error <", miu$abs.error))
```

You can see the structure of `miu` by running `str(miu)`, which will show you the names of each object in the list.

Also, you can see what the print function is doing for the output of `integrate` by running `getAnywhere(print.integrate)`, which will show you the function code.

Answer (score 2):

We can use `glue` to do this

```
glue::glue("The true mean is: {round(miu$value, 3)} with absolute error < {round(min$abs.error, 3)}")
```